# how to loop music from extranal

Tags: java, android, android-intent

try to do but can't loop my music from extranal on mobile 
i don't know why not look at my code on setOnCompletionListener methods

sorry from my bad english ... Thx for watch

```js
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_audio_effects);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        updatePlaylist();
            Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/" + songs.get(0));
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, video);
            mMediaPlayer.start();
                 mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
            mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);
            setupVisualizerFxAndUI();//อันนี้แสดง คลื่นเสียง
            setupEqualizerFxAndUI();
            mVisualizer.setEnabled(true);//อันนี้แสดง คลื่นเสียง
            mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
 
                    mVisualizer.setEnabled(false);//อันนี้แสดง คลื่นเสียง
                    i++;
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    if (i < songs.size()) {
                        try {
                            Uri video = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/" + songs.get(i));
                            if (video != null) {
                                mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AudioFxActivity.this, video);
 //                               mEqualizer = new Equalizer(0, mMediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
                                mMediaPlayer.start();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            // report a crash
                            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), ex.getMessage());
                        }
                    } else {
                        // done with media player
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                        mMediaPlayer = null;
                    }
                }
            });mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

this is my problems

Comment: this all my code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7c978b7dba5b1ea8268e

Comment: When you say you can't, are you getting an error?

Comment: my problem is music not loop when after song[0] onCompletion
music is stop! i want start next music and next to Finally my array songs